# Getting the total for a number of fields

Tags: swiftui

I have an app that records costs for a car.  I can't work out how to create a field that keeps a running total for the ongoing costs.  In the ContentView file I have a struct that defines what an expense is, which includes the 'amount'.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks.

There are 2 files, ContentView, and Addview;

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var expenseList = ExpenseList()
    @State private var isShowingAddView = false
    @State private var totalCost = 0.0
        
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                    Text("Total Cost").font(.headline) //just holding a place for future code
                }
                Form {
                    List {
                        ForEach(expenseList.itemList) { trans in
                            HStack{
                                Text(trans.item)
                                    .font(.headline)
                                Spacer()
                                VStack(alignment: .trailing) {
                                    
                                    HStack {
                                        Text("Amount: ")
                                            .font(.caption).bold()
                                        Text(trans.amount, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
                                            .font(.caption)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: removeItems)
                    }
                }
                .navigationTitle("Expenditure")
                .toolbar {
                    Button {
                        isShowingAddView = true
                    } label: {
                        Image(systemName: "plus")
                    }
                }
                .sheet(isPresented: $isShowingAddView) {
                    AddView(expenseList: expenseList)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    func removeItems(at offsets: IndexSet) {
        expenseList.itemList.remove(atOffsets: offsets)
    }
}

class ExpenseList: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var itemList = [ExpenseItem]() {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(itemList) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "Things")
            }
        }
    }
    init() {
        if let savedItems = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Things") {
            if let decodedItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([ExpenseItem].self, from: savedItems) {
                itemList = decodedItems
                return
            }
        }
        itemList = []
    }
}

struct ExpenseItem: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    let item: String
    let amount: Double
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

```
import SwiftUI

struct AddView: View {
    
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    @ObservedObject var expenseList: ExpenseList
    @State private var item = "Fuel"
    @State private var amount = 0.0
    let itemType = ["Fuel", "Tyres"]

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                Picker("Type", selection: $item) {
                    ForEach(itemType, id: \.self) {
                        Text($0)
                    }
                }
                TextField("Enter amount...", value: $amount, format: .currency(code: "USD"))
            }
            .navigationTitle("Add an item...")
            .toolbar {
                Button("Save") {
                    let trans = ExpenseItem(item: item, amount: amount)
                    expenseList.itemList.append(trans)
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct AddView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        AddView(expenseList: ExpenseList())
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to do `... create a field that keeps a running total for the ongoing costs`. This is just one way.
Try this approach, using an extra var `totalCost` in your `ExpenseList` and a summation.

```
class ExpenseList: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published private (set) var totalCost = 0.0  // <-- here

    @Published var itemList = [ExpenseItem]() {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(itemList) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "Things")
            }
            totalCost = itemList.map{ $0.amount }.reduce(0.0, { $0 + $1 }) // <-- here
        }
    }
    init() {
        if let savedItems = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Things") {
            if let decodedItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([ExpenseItem].self, from: savedItems) {
                itemList = decodedItems
                return
            }
        }
        itemList = []
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
 Text("Total Cost: \(expenseList.totalCost)").font(.headline)
```

You can of course do this, without adding any extra var:

```
 Text("Total Cost: \(expenseList.itemList.map{ $0.amount }.reduce(0.0, { $0 + $1 }))")
```

Comment: if my answer helped, could you mark it as accepted please. Use the tick mark, it turns green.

Comment: Where is the tick mark??

Comment: it should be near the `1 Answer` just below the up and down arrows. I can't see it because I'm not the poster. If you don't see it, maybe it's because you do not have enough points. In that case try to click the up arrow.