# Update Details on a List SwiftUI

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm fairly new to SwiftUI and I'm trying to update the details on a list and then save it.

I am able to get the details to update, but every time I try saving I'm not able to do it.

I have marked the area where I need help. Thanks in advance.

// This is the Array to store the items:

```
struct ExpenseItem : Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let amount: Int
}
```

// This is the UserDefault Array

```
class Expenses: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var items = [ExpenseItem]() {
        didSet {
            if let encoded = try? JSONEncoder().encode(items) {
                UserDefaults.standard.set(encoded, forKey: "Items")
            }
        }
    }
    
    init() {
        if let savedItems = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: "Items") {
            if let decodedItems = try? JSONDecoder().decode([ExpenseItem].self, from: savedItems) {
                items = decodedItems
                return
            }
        }

        items = []
    }
}
```

// View to add details :

```
struct AddView: View {
    @State private var name = ""
    @State private var amount = 0
    @StateObject var expenses: Expenses
    @Environment(\.dismiss) var dismiss
    var body: some View {
        Form {
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
            Text("\(amount)")
            Button("Tap Me") {
                amount += 1
            }
        }
        .navigationTitle("Add New Count")
        .toolbar {
            if name != "" {
                Button("Save") {
                    let item = ExpenseItem(name: name, amount: amount)
                    expenses.items.append(item)
                    dismiss()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

// This is the file to update the details:

```
struct UpdateDhikr: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var expenses : Expenses
    
    @State var name : String
    @State var amount : Int
    
    var body: some View {
        
        Form {
            
            TextField("Name", text: $name)
            Text("\(amount)")
            Button("Tap Me") {
                amount += 1
            }
            
        }
        .navigationTitle("Update Count")
        .toolbar {
            if name != "" {
                Button("Save") {
                    // This is where I'm having problems.
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The error is telling you that in the `View` before `AddView` in the hierarachy, you do not have
`@StateObject var expenses = Expenses()` that you then pass to `AddView`, using
`AddView(expenses: expenses)`, where you declare `@ObservedObject var expenses: Expenses`.

Comment: Did you google the error? It is always the same answer you have to inject the object where you are getting the error.

Comment: have a look at how this guy did his school assignment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73551093/getting-the-total-for-a-number-of-fields/73551206#73551206

Comment: Googling the error did nothing for me. Please ignore the error. Is there a way to save the updated details this way. I have marked the part where I’m having trouble to save the updated information. Im not able to find a way to save the updated information.